# Single sign on with an external AMS?

Tags: 8, users

In Drupal 8, how would you go about changing the registration/login process to check with an external source like Personify or NetForum to 'log in' a user to Drupal?

Answer (score 2):

The [CAS](https://www.drupal.org/project/cas) module has a quite stable [8.x-1.0-beta2](https://www.drupal.org/project/cas/releases/8.x-1.0-beta2) release. Take a look at the source code of [cas.module](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/cas/tree/cas.module) and which hooks it uses to overrule the regular user actions like registration, login and logout.

(If that doesn't answer your question, please be more specific about which AMS you'd like to implement.)

Comment: NetForum, specifically.